# Finding Element in json file with python

Tags: python, json, macos

I've writen a script to scrape a site. In the html of that site i managed to find the json file that I want. That's the json https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/Product-Variation?dwvar_J143632_color=&pid=J143632&quantity=1

In this json I want to find a specific element, by input another element. Let me explain.
The part I'm interested in is this:

```
{
    "attributeId": "size",
    "displayName": "Size",
    "id": "size",
    "swatchable": false,
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "WFOX04-2",
        "description": null,
        "displayValue": "36",
        "value": "WFOX04-2",
        "selected": false,
        "selectable": true,
        "availability": 1,
        "productID": "2000138270021",
        "price": 120,
        "url": "https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/Product-Variation?dwvar_J143632_color=F19-105&dwvar_J143632_size=WFOX04-2&pid=J143632&quantity=1"
      },
      {
        "id": "WFOX04-3",
        "description": null,
        "displayValue": "36.5",
        "value": "WFOX04-3",
        "selected": false,
        "selectable": true,
        "availability": 1,
        "productID": "2000138270038",
        "price": 120,
        "url": "https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/Product-Variation?dwvar_J143632_color=F19-105&dwvar_J143632_size=WFOX04-3&pid=J143632&quantity=1"
```

I want to input a "displayValue" like '36', and if the script can find that value it has to print the "productID".
I searched on this forum, googled and tried a lot but failed every time. The last code I wrote is this:

```
from jsondb.db import Database 
data = Database('/Users/MIKE/Desktop/EIS_BOT/File.json')
for id in data['sizes']:
if element['displayValue'] == '36':
    print('36 in stock')
    print(element['productID'])
    break
else:
    print ('36 not in stock')
```

Thanks. 
Edit: the code isn't all here obviously, it's much more, but it perfectly work until this point

Comment: Leaving the fact that code doesn't compile aside, did you mean: `for element in data['values']:`?

Comment: Where is `element` defined? This code is incomplete

Comment: Yeah @CristiFati you are right, I made a mistake there. And how should I define element?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
if element['displayValue'] == '36':
```

to

```
if '36' in element['displayValue']:
```

this will return any string that has 36 in it.

Comment: I got this error: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(row)? But i don't understand why

Comment: @LikeMike Your error is unrelated to this answer. `print` is a statement in python 2, and `print` is a function in python 3. `print row` is valid in python 2, but must be changed to `print(row)` in python 3.

Comment: Your code does not run at all. I'm not sure where this error is happening but print statements need parentheses

Comment: But parentheses are there, I don't understand where I'm supposed to add them

Comment: So, your code in this question is broken. I have no idea how to help you because what you have posted here is wrong. If you post the full, actual code then I can try to debug for you, but the KeyError is telling you that you're trying to reference a Key in the dictionary/json that does not exist.